# Add multiple dates PHP

Tags: php

I'm currently busy with my front page header. When it's almost Christmas or when it's Christmas, add the `xmas` class.

```
<?php if(date("d-m") == "25-12") { echo ' class="xmas"'; } ?>
```

The above script works, however, I want to add the following dates without having to repeat the script;

```
<?php if(date("d-m") == "25-12" OR "26-12" OR "27-12" OR "28-12" OR "29-12" OR "30-12") { echo ' class="xmas"'; } ?>
```

**That doesn't work** but it's an example of how I want it to be.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: Lot of hits for *"if date in range php"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if(in_array(date("d-m"), ["25-12", "26-12", "27-12", "28-12", "29-12", "30-12"])) { echo ' class="xmas"'; } ?>
```

Checking if the date is in the required range would be the cleanest option though.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the date in range script but that's a quite big script and I'm looking for something clean and simple. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it a little bit differently:

```
<?php
  if(date('m') == 12 && ($d = date('d')) >= 25 && $d <= 30)){
    // do your stuff.
    // Better for performance because:
    // - There is no need to grab the day of the month, if the month is not december.
    // - If it isn't december, the code after && is not executed.
  }

  function in_range($i, $start, $end){
    return $i >= $start && $i <= $end;
  }

  if(date('m') == 12 && in_range(date('d'), 25, 30){
    // do your stuff.
    // Better for code reuse ability.
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by putting the dates you are interested in into an array, theydo not have to be contiguous or even in a logical order.

```
$special_dates = ["25-12", "01-04", "31-12", "29-02", "21-06"];
```

This is easy to read and maintain.

Then using the `in_array()` function you can do

```
if ( in_array(date("d-m"), $special_dates) ) {
    // It's a special date
} else {
    // just an ordinary date
}
```

Comment: Let's only hope they're not looking for something "even simpler/shorter" there Smokey ;-)

Answer (score 0):

could always check the day of the year...

```
if(date('z') >= 358) {
...
}
```

or if you really don't want it showing on 31st December:

```
if(date('z') >= 358 && date('z') <= 364) {
...
}
```

needs tweaking for leap years (359 instead of 358)